# How can I improve my visibility as a remote employee?

Tags: professionalism, career-development

I look after a remote territory for an American startup.
I keep generating new leads even if I am a technical person.
Small things are ignored until they become big.
Big things are taken away by senior management.
And my colleague, who does Sales, seems to be the one to get credit for what happens, even when I did most, or all the job.
My line manager told me "keep building relationships with people in the main office".

My question is: how can I improve my visibility, so that the company knows what I am doing and I can get credit for it?

Comment: I'm not sure there's currently really enough information here to answer properly (it's similar to [Handling Credit-takers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/366)). How are you presenting these leads? Does this affect your performance reviews? How are they taking credit? Have you considered asking to / can you handle the sales yourself? What are these small/big things and how are they related to your question? How is what your manager said related to the question?

Comment: @Dukeling we don't have performance reviews at all. My manager is a VP and highly visible, my Sales colleague tries to be in the face of senior management as much as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I avoid being transparent, so that the company knows what I am
>   doing and I can get credit for it?

The traditional method would be to provide regular reports listing your activities, and tracking them through leads and eventually sales.

But from your prior questions, it appears very unlikely that this will get what you think you deserve.

You wrote: "the idea is to use my contacts to help the company grow, and be rewarded in turn". That seems to be your idea. But it doesn't seem to be shared by your company.

It seems that your vision for your role differs from that of your company. I suspect the company knows exactly what you are doing, but isn't willing to give you the "credit" you feel is due.

This isn't about "being transparent". It's about your lack of a formal sales plan that gives you compensation for generating leads. You should push for a formal compensation package that meets your needs. But be  prepared to leave if you don't get it.

Answer (score 8):

Copy people into your Lead generation emails.

Or prepare and send a regular email report detailing the leads you generated and which generated business and which were lost/not developed (and for what reason).

Comment: A weekly summary of your activity to your boss should suffice here.

Comment: I have been doing that from day one. My boss is updated on what's happening in the territory, and the Salesperson (cc'ed) uses this information, when needed, to complement his own reports. I don't know everything Salesperson is doing, but I am being as professional as possible in keeping the team up to date.