# Concerned about scrum master trying to take credit for my work, how to approach boss?

Tags: software-industry, software, bullying

I am writing a document for our team. Our team is supposed to submit feedback on it, and I am supposed to upload my work to a shared drive for it to be read/reviewed. Under the guise of turning the manual into a sharepoint to make it easier for users to comment on it, the scrum master made it a sharepoint that is stored on **his local drive**, and not the shared drive. Someone also made anonymous comments in the sharepoint about not wanting attributions (i.e. article written by) on articles in the sharepoint. Given this scrum master's history I am concerned he is trying to steal my work, due to  the move of the document to his local drive from the shared drive and the comments regarding that he thinks there shouldn't be attributions (article written by:) on each article. My guess is he is probably going to take the contents of the sharepoint document and post them as his own work.

I plan to bring it (with proof) to my manager's attention, but I keep bringing proof to his office of different things, and during his last talk although he was trying to keep a neutral stance and make it seem like he was still going to continue to back up the actions of the scrum master, he actually started to give little tells/make comments that he was beginning to question the actions of the scrum master and is coming over to my side of things. It’s just humiliating to keep walking in there with ‘proof.’ It makes me feel like I’m being a 5 year-old tattle tale, except for I am truly being bullied. This would easily be the most significant thing I’d be presenting him with, though.

**QUESTION:** I also plan to say that I want to be removed from the story and will also submit it in writing. But the real question is - should I be removing my work from the shared drive, and wiping the sharepoint document clean? It is all content that I created 100% by myself with no help from anyone else on our team. In addition, is there anything you can tell me that would be helpful in presenting this proof to my boss?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling Credit-takers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/366/handling-credit-takers)

Answer (score 4):

You were paid to do that work. You do *not* get to withdraw it. Doing so will get you fired; the last thing a company needs is a petulant saboteur.

Answer (score 3):

Don't ask us, ask your manager.
Your company may have policies about keeping track of things properly that may be violated by this, which would make this an easy one.
Even if not, if your manager shares your concerns, they will tell you what to do.

How to present proof:
Dont' present proof, present facts.
Your job isn't to proof that the scrum master is doing domething shady. That makes the whole thing controversial.

Simply state facts (this is a private sharefolder), state risks (lack of traceability of work, for example), and ask how to proceed. If this keeps coming up, your manager should be able to connect the dots and see if they can do something about the scrummaster.
By how you phrase it, I presume the scrummmaster is not directly under your manager, so your manager will have to convince other people.

Bonus points for presenting the facts in writing.
Since you aren't accusing anybody of anything, merely stating facts, you cover your ass for later and start producing the papertrail your manager will need to eventually do something about the ScrumMaster.